# Cordova config.xml getting override

Tags: windows, visual-studio, cordova

I set up a basic Cordova project, and whenever I run cordova build, the config.xml file in Windows gets re-written to defaults, I added the following lines to change the icon of my project. When I run the project I can see that my icon have been changed but when I go to the **bld/Debug/platforms/windows/config.xml** it is in the default format and I cannot see the lines that I have added. So i get the default cordova icon instead. So I cannot deploy the app to the windows store. Very strange. Is anyone got any idea about this.

```
<platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/logo.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/smalllogo.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/storelogo.png" width="50" height="50" />
  </platform>
```

Thank you

Comment: Are you changing the config.xml in the root of your project?

Comment: Hi Joerg yes I am changing it in the root

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not surround it with platform and try it like this. It should work.

```
<icon src="res/icons/windows/logo.png" platform="windows8" width="150" height="150" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/smalllogo.png" platform="windows8" width="30" height="30" />
<icon src="res/icons/windows/storelogo.png" platform="windows8" width="50" height="50" />
```

Comment: I know OP accepted this question but I am having the same issue and this answer does not solve my issue. Can you please explain why this is happening and how I would solve this for android not windows. I add 'platform="android"' but it doesn't work